# How to assign values to all properties of class in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a class with private properties:

```
class A implements IA {
   private id: number;
   private name: string;

   constructor(obj: IA) {
      // Set here properties from obj
   }
}
```

I want to pass object `IA` with initialized values when I create instance A, and refill only that properties in class, which I passed.

`new A({id: 1})` or `new A({id: 1, name: "O"})`

How to do this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to just use `Object.assign`. It will only copy the fileds specified in the constructor parameter.

```
interface IA{
    id? : number;
    name? : string
}

class A {
    private id: number;
    private name: string;

    constructor(obj: IA) {
        Object.assign(this, obj)
    }
}
```

**Note** I removed the implements from the class since private fields can't be the implentation for an interface

Comment: Does it work only with properties or with methods also? Does it matter access modifiers of properties?

Comment: @OPV it will copy every field of `obj` regardless of type (methods included if they are specified on the object). Modifiers are not taken into account `Object.assign ` is a Javascript function it has no knowledge of Typescript access modifiers

Comment: Is it correct when property in interface is pubic, but in class private?

Comment: It works, but I get also new object in class as `obj` with the same data

Comment: @OPV All fields in interfaces are public there is no possibility to specify access modifiers in interfaces. Only public members can be an implementation for interfaces, so privates can't be an implementation

Comment: @OPV not sure I get your last comment

Comment: If to do `console.log(new A({id: 1, name: 'O' }))` I see structure as: `id, name, obj: {}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179274/discussion-between-opv-and-titian-cernicova-dragomir).