# How to write a class constructor that takes Partial<Class> as argument?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I would like to write a class constructor that takes Partial as argument.

Below are my code.

```
type UserInterface = {
  username: string
  passcode: number;
}

class User implements UserInterface {
  username = 'Default username';
  passcode = 1234

  constructor(args: Partial<User>) {
    for (const key in args) {
      if (key in User) {
        this[key as keyof this] = args[key as keyof typeof args];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However TypeScript failed to compile my code.

```
Type 'string | number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'this[keyof this]'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'this[keyof this]'.
```

What am I missing?

---

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52136787/14605338 is not a solution as it do not validate if a property exist in class.

Comment: `User` class does not have static props. What type of `key` do you expect here `key in User`?

Comment: @captain-yossarian `username` and `passcode`

Comment: these are props of class instance, not class itself

Comment: @captain-yossarian Doesn't `this['username']` an equivalent of `this.username`?

Comment: But we are talking about `key in User`

Comment: What should I use instead to check if `User` has the property `key`?