# How to assign values of an object in constructor to all properties of class?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to easily assign all of the properties in an object in a constructor to all of the properties in a class

```
type tCustomUpload = {
    name : string,
    relationship : string,
    priority : number,
    id : number
}
class CustomUpload {
    name : string;
    relationship : string;
    priority : number;
    id : number;
    constructor (payload : tCustomUpload) {
        Object.assign(this, payload);
    }
}
```

I tried the answer at [How to assign values to all properties of class in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52136739/how-to-assign-values-to-all-properties-of-class-in-typescript) but there are 2 issues with that answer

1. the interface has optional properties, whereas I want them required
2. typescript actually flags that answer as having errors, along the lines of `Property 'x' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.`

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4FwTwBwU3BhArgZzAewLYFUoBs0CGAJsALzADeAUKMAJAB2BGcAXMKgE4CWDA5gBoaoOpxi4CYbmgbIAFtyjB2XXoOEg6UHmh6RlwBogwAjGJyG063EuyOnzG4AF8nAYwnJkwJKkw58YkonRmY2DjAefgBuELEJKRl5RQNVGJDtaT0IA3szTlirG1zjfMKRNyTIxDd0TmAACigCCEDbBBR0bDxCIgBKYKs6AHkTACsYWoA6Ai9uPgYGsAVkAWBm1t6+8s1XWmcgA)

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript doesn't really iterate over properties to assign with `Object.assign` the way you're wanting it to. It's less type-safe, but you can assert that the properties exist with `!:`.

```
type tCustomUpload = {
    name: string,
    relationship: string,
    priority: number,
    id: number
}
class CustomUpload {
    name!: string;
    relationship!: string;
    priority!: number;
    id!: number;
    constructor(payload: tCustomUpload) {
        Object.assign(this, payload);
    }
}
```